# No values for a SQL query in a view

Tags: sql-server, jpa, view

I'm doing a query to a view in JPA but it does not give me any value or error

Query (View is vwVistaCartera)

```
Query query=em.createQuery("select r from vwVistaCartera r",vwVistaCartera.class);
List<vwVistaCartera> vistaCartera=query.getResultList();
return vistaCartera;
```

Then in the console I do not have any value, perform tests with other tables, it returns data but in the view it does not.

note: my jdbc is sqljdbc42.7.jar

UPDATE

My Entity is:

```
@Entity
public class vwVistaCartera implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String ruc;
    private String nombre;
    private String telefono2;
    private String trans;
    private String saldo;
    private Date FechaVenci;
//getters & setters
}
```

LOG SQL

```
 Hibernate: select vwvistacar0_.ruc as ruc1_1_, vwvistacar0_.FechaVenci as FechaVen2_1_, vwvistacar0_.nombre as nombre3_1_, vwvistacar0_.saldo as saldo4_1_, vwvistacar0_.telefono2 as telefono5_1_, vwvistacar0_.trans as trans6_1_ from vwVistaCartera vwvistacar0_
```

Comment: Why are you aliasing your table with the same name a column? This will actually work of but is horribly confusing. And not quite sure where the issue is here. Does the view return data?

Comment: Hi, @Sean the view from the database, it does have data, but since jpa does not return anything

Comment: Here's an idea, you look in the LOG of the JPA provider for what SQL is being invoked, and likely then you have your answer. You don't post any JPA entity class so impossible to say more without crystal balls

Comment: Hi, @DN1 This gives me the LOG `Hibernate: select vwvistacar0_.ruc as ruc1_1_, vwvistacar0_.FechaVenci as FechaVen2_1_, vwvistacar0_.nombre as nombre3_1_, vwvistacar0_.saldo as saldo4_1_, vwvistacar0_.telefono2 as telefono5_1_, vwvistacar0_.trans as trans6_1_ from vwVistaCartera vwvistacar0`

Comment: Note: tags (such as JPA) should not be added to the title of questions.

Comment: @DN1 I published it.  thanks!!!